# Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type '"void"

Tags: angular, observable, subscribe

Hi I am working on a angular web api project and I am getting this error on subscribe keyword, also imported observable but error is same. So if anyone has encounter this before kindly help.

**employee.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
import { EmployeeService } from 'src/app/shared/employee.service';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/maps';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-employee',
  templateUrl: './employee.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./employee.component.css']
})
export class EmployeeComponent implements OnInit {
 
  constructor(public service: EmployeeService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.resetForm();
  }
  resetForm(form?: NgForm) {
    if (form != null)
      form.resetForm();
    this.service.formData = {
      EmployeeID: null,
      FullName: '',
      Position: '',
      EMPCode: '',
      Mobile: ''
}
  }
  onSubmit(form: NgForm) {
    if (form.value.EmployeeID == null)
      this.insertRecord(form);
  }
      insertRecord(form: NgForm) {
        this.service.postEmployee(form.value).subscribe(res  => {           
     
         this.resetForm(form);
       
        });
  }
}
```

Comment: You need to share at least the code for the `postEmployee` function, otherwise we're not able to help you

Comment: did you use ```return``` on your ```postEmployee()``` service?

Comment: yes after using the return method, I am getting error at this.service.postEmployee line 

Code :
insertRecord(form: NgForm) {
        return{
       this.service.postEmployee(form.value).subscribe((res: any[]): void=> {     
        
          this.toastr.success('Inserted successfully', 'Employee Details');
      
         this.resetForm(form);
        this.service.refreshList();
        }),
  }
} @KibéM.C

Comment: Pretty sure you did not return anything from the employee.service.ts file in whatever you are using from the class EmployeeService. Do that and the problem will be fixed

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

insertRecord(form: NgForm):Observable<any> {
 return this.service.postEmployee(form.value).pipe(map(((res: any[]): void=> { 

this.toastr.success('Inserted successfully', 'Employee Details'); 

this.resetForm(form); this.service.refreshList(); }), } }
```